# Lifetime issues with a generic async callback stored in a struct

Tags: rust, callback, lifetime

I am trying to create an object that stores a pointer to an async generic (with trait bounds) callback, but I struggle having everything functional, mostly due to lifetime conflicts that seem hard to resolve even though I try to follow compiler' suggestions.

I really struggle to understand how to solve, and now I end up in a situation where, in the method of my struct that actually calls my stored callback, `self` seem to be considered as not living "long enough", compared to the lifetime of my callback :

```rust
17 | impl<'a, 'b, T> ModalActionData<'a, 'b, T>
   |          -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
36 |     pub async fn call(&mut self) -> CallbackReturnType {
   |                       - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
37 |         (self.callback)(self.actionable, &mut self.data_sender).await
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'b`
```

Knowing that `ModalActionData` has the following structure :

```rust
pub struct ModalActionData<'a, 'b, T>
where
    T: ModalActionable,
    'a: 'b,
{
    pub action: String,
    pub actionable: &'a T,
    pub callback: Box<ModalActionCallback<'a, 'b, T>>,
    pub data_sender: DummyDataSender<String>,
}
```

And `ModalActionCallback` is defined like following :

```rust
pub type CallbackReturnType = Result<(), ()>;
pub type AsyncCallbackReturnType<'a> = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = CallbackReturnType> + 'a>>;
pub type ModalActionCallback<'a, 'b, T> =
    fn(&'a T, &'b mut DummyDataSender<String>) -> AsyncCallbackReturnType<'b>;
```

I tried to play with lifetimes, `Pin<Box<...>>`, adding `'static` lifetimes here and there, adding/removing constraints on lifetimes and brute-forcing my way through this issue, but none of this worked

Here is a minimalistic [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11deba55566e92c33322f7084c7f9e27) that reproduces my issue in a single file, and shows the error message I have on my real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is needed is that the reference to `self` outlives `'b` so we give it a name and bind it to `'b`:

```rust
pub async fn call<'c: 'b>(&'c mut self) -> CallbackReturnType {
```